# Find a list which has date in Python?

Tags: python, list

```
l=[["22/01/1997", "a", " c"],["d","e","f"],["23/07/1997", "f"," 1"]]
```

Find a list which starts with date

Output:

```
l=[["22/01/1997", "a", " c"],["23/07/1997", "f"," 1"]]
```

Comment: Is the date in fixed format dd/mm/yyyy ? is it a string containing date, or an actual datetime date object?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

```py
from datetime import datetime

l = [["22/01/1997", "a", " c"],["d","e","f"],["23/07/1997", "f"," 1"]]
new_l = []
for elem in l:
    try:
        datetime.strptime(elem[0], "%d/%m/%Y")
        new_l.append(elem)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

#### Output

```
[['22/01/1997', 'a', ' c'], ['23/07/1997', 'f', ' 1']]
```